# Looping through unique (excluding a single column) values in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uniq

I am keeping track of which users edit text files stored as database entries.

I have a credit model that keeps track of the user, file edited, and a timestamp of when the edit occurred.

In my controller, I have a query that selects the editors of an entry, and joins a time stamp from the credit model.

```
@editors = User.select("name, users.id, credit.created_at").joins("INNER JOIN credits ON credits.user_id = users.id WHERE credit.file_id = " + x)
```

In my view, I do not want to display duplicate editors, but the unique timestamp that is joined to the user is causing duplicate editors to print

```
<% @editors.uniq.reverse_each do |e| %>
    <%= link_to e.name, user_path(e.id) %>
    <%= e.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way that I can exclude a certain column from the uniq comparison in my view?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't quite serve my particular needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest solution. but this is what I would do if I was a time crunch

```
<% editor_id = 0 %>
<% @editors.uniq.reverse_each do |e| %>
    <% unless editor_id == e.id %>
      <%= link_to e.name, user_path(e.id) %>
      <%= e.created_at %>
      <% editor_id = e.id %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I am doing here is initializing a variable called **editor_id** and then check if its the same a the editor id. if its false then it displays the editor

I hope that this helps and puts you in the right track